# How to set the window size of a particular buffer to spawn?

Tags: window, window-configuration

For example, when programming, say I want to open the repl shell for the source file that I'm editing, each time the window size of repl shell buffer occupies half of frame size after spawned. I then have to manually adjust it to the desired smaller size of the height

I want to set the window size of that particular buffer to spawn, and possibly the ability to also set window sizes for other particular buffers.

Are there any packages to do this, though I haven't found out one on the internet, if not, how to implement such a feature?

Comment: [There's documentation for how to resize window](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Resizing-Windows.html), you basically want to create a function that sets the size you want, and then add it to the major-mode hook of the repl. With that said, my personal opinion is that you'll get into corner cases of having varying number of splits where the hardcoded size would screw configuration up. I myself instead just set `pop-up-windows` to `nil`, [excluding magit](https://github.com/Hi-Angel/dotfiles/blob/90db086e2620183f3c95cc745e87d4834bdc66e9/.emacs#L1600-L1610).

Comment: Prot posted a video explaining in detail how to get finely-detailed control over window placement just last week: https://protesilaos.com/codelog/2024-02-08-emacs-window-rules-display-buffer-alist/